# Venmo integration issue

Tags: android, payment-gateway, credit-card, venmo

I want to integrate my app with vemmo payment gateway. I am following steps from this [tutorial](https://github.com/venmo/app-switch-android). After having done this it display login page for venmo as I haven't installed venmo app in my device. After this I logged in then it displays me this screen shown in screenshot.

[image]

It doesn't have button to make a payment.

Is there anything that I have to do explicitly to display pay button.

Please guide me how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Give a reason to downvote.

Comment: Hey , Have you got any solution for this issue ? 
I have the same issue 
need ur help